# Error1 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form4' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments'

Tags: c#, windows

i have 3 forms
how i pass the values of form1 and form 2 and on form 4 but this show error

```
public Form4(string value, string value1, string value2,string value3 )
{
     InitializeComponent();
     textBox1.Text=value;
     textBox2.Text=value1;

     textBox3.Text=value2;
     textBox4.Text=value3;
}
```

Comment: The error seems obvious. You are anywhere in your code doing something like `Form4 frm=new Form4(parameter1,parameter2)`...

Comment: //form2                                                                                                                           Form4 form22=new Form4(textBox3.Text , textBox4.Text);
            form22.Show();

Comment: What line is throwing that error? You are passing in 2 arguments when 4 are needed. To help we need to know which ones you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are anywhere in your code calling a `Form4`constructor with 2 parameters, but you have not defined it. Either you add this new constructor:

```
public Form4(string value, string value1)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   textBox1.Text=value;
   textBox2.Text=value1;
}
```

Or you must change your form creation:

```
Form4 form22=new Form4(textBox3.Text , textBox4.Text,"",""); 
form22.Show();
```

Comment: Well.. i don't have a cristal ball. I don't know what is your form2 code, or what exception is throwing you now :)

Comment: error is removed but are not passing the values of form2 on form3

Comment: That's a different thing. Maybe you should edit your question and adding the relevant code of your form1 and form2.

Comment: ' Form4 form22=new Form4(textBox3.Text , textBox4.Text,"","");
            form22.Show(); '

Comment: i am passing the values of form1 and form2 on form3, error is removed of your code but not pass the value of form2 on form3

Comment: With that code, you are passing 2 textboxes text, 3 and 4. If you want to pass others, just replace `""` with them. What you must have in mind is that there must be always 4 parameters